# IntelliJ Spring Boot - java: error: invalid source release: 15

Tags: java

I'm trying to run my very first Spring Application in IntelliJ and I ran into the following error:

`java: error: invalid source release: 15`

When creating my project, I set everything to Java 11:

- module spring_chat has Target bytcode version set to 11
- module SDK is corretto-11
- project SDK is corretto-11
- project language level is 11

In my pom.xml it also says Java Version 11:

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>spring_chat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring_chat</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm upvoting you. Me, it's Java 5 it complains against, when it has a Java 17 installed...

Comment: Have you reloaded the pom.xml into intellij? Do you remember if anything said Java 15?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your full `pom.xml` (not just a snippet).

Comment: can you provide more logs of the output error?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have something like this in your POM:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
       ...
```

(with `<java.version>11</java.version>` for property, elsewhere.
Because you could be lacking a `<target>` declaration.